# No archive in Xcode 4.3+ 4.6 Organizer when Building adHoc IPA for Testflight

Tags: xcode, ipa, testflight, ad-hoc-distribution, organizer

When try to build IPA file for Testflight there was just a zero xarchive file and it didn't appear in the Organizer panel in Xcode 4.6.3. I checked the libraries for Skip install...but no solution.

It worked earlier and worked with all other apps, so I don't think that there could be any settings problem in the Xcode.
I have two targets a full and lite version.
There was no any warning or error log just didn't happen anything even the archiving runs without problem.

Read and tried all the hectic answer in this topic but no solution.

Answer (score 0):

Solved the problem myself. The most important rule is simple and based on this it could be understandable all the various solutions which caused the confusion:

```
THERE COULD BE JUST ONE TARGET WITH Skip install---> NO 
and all the others must be YES!
```

[image]

The second "NO" could come with a new target file or library which you added to your project.

Some additional fact:

1. Must use Product--->Archive NOT Product--->Build for Archiving
2. Project file has no effect on this

In my case the problem was the second target which I added later and as the default is Skip install ----> NO, so it was left with two NO.